# Bootstrap File Input no visualiza la imagen seleccionada

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap

Recupero datos desde `PHP` y los almaceno en `JSON` para manipularlos desde `jQuery`. Al seleccionar un registro de una lista, el primer registro me visualiza los datos correctamente, pero al seleccionar otro registro ya no me visualiza la imagen (los demás datos en los otros `input` se ven correctamente).

Cabe destacar que uso el plugin [Bootstrap File Input](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput) para manipular las imágenes.

Anexo el código que estoy usando:

```
function editarSlide(idSlide) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "URL?op=getID",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            idSlide: idSlide
        },
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {

            $("#imagenSlideActual").fileinput({
                initialPreview: [
                    '../img/home/'+response.imagen_slide
                ],
            });

            $("#emarca").val(response.marca_slide);
            $("#edescripcion").val(response.desc_slide);
            $("#eliga").val(response.liga_slide);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te sucede es que la primera vez que llamas al plugin, inicializas el `file input` correctamente, pero la segunda vez que lo llamas en el mismo elemento, ya se encuentra inicializado y [se ignorará dicha operación](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput/blob/95f055b93441b7b88582c64fb4fea1f34a2f7a9d/js/fileinput.js#L3018).

Observa los siguientes *snippets*:

Como verás, dentro del `setInterval` se inicializa el plugin cada un segundo, cada vez usando una imagen diferente como `initialPreview`. Pero en este primer *snippet* solo verás la primera imagen (en los siguientes intentos de inicializar el plugin, el mismo ya se encuentra inicializado):

```js
var images = [
  "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_woods.jpg",
  "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_5terre.jpg",
  "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_lights.jpg"
];
var index = 0;

setInterval(function () {
  $("#myInput").fileinput({
    initialPreview: [images[index]],
    initialPreviewAsData: true
  });
  index++;
  if (index === images.length) { index = 0; }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.6/css/fileinput.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.6/js/plugins/piexif.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.6/js/plugins/sortable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.6/js/plugins/purify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.6/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.6/themes/fa/theme.js"></script>

<div class="file-loading">
    <input id="myInput" name="myInput" type="file" multiple>
</div>
```

Este segundo *snippet* realiza lo mismo, pero esta vez destruyendo el `file input` usando el método [destroy](https://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/plugin-methods#destroy) y volviendo a inicializarlo en cada iteración:

```js
var images = [
  "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_woods.jpg",
  "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_5terre.jpg",
  "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_lights.jpg"
];
var index = 0;

setInterval(function () {
  $("#myInput")
    .fileinput("destroy")
    .fileinput({
      initialPreview: [images[index]],
      initialPreviewAsData: true
    });
  index++;
  if (index === images.length) { index = 0; }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.6/css/fileinput.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.6/js/plugins/piexif.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.6/js/plugins/sortable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.6/js/plugins/purify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.6/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.6/themes/fa/theme.js"></script>

<div class="file-loading">
    <input id="myInput" name="myInput" type="file" multiple>
</div>
```

Comment: Agradezco tu observación, me ha servido bastante.